# Need to remove space between two elements inside of a React-Bootstrap Column

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I have an SVG and a `<p>` element that are both wrapped together inside of an anchor tag.

The anchor around the SVG and `<p>` element all live inside of container.

I have styles for the container element as well as the `<p>` element to position them next to each other and centered in the middle of the parent element which is a React-Bootstrap column.

Right now the SVG is sitting directly on top of the `<p>` element and if I remove out the anchor tag element there is a large gap between the SVG and the `<p>` element however they sit on the same line together and are aligned correctly.

I have the React HTML and the corresponding styling below. Any ideas on how to get these to line up properly?

`HTML`

```
<Col>
  <ClipboardContainer>
    <a href={url}>
      <ClipboardSvgLarge /><p>view order status ></p>
    </a>
  </ClipboardContainer> 
</Col>
```

`Styled Components CSS`

```
const ClipboardContainer = styled('div')((props) => ({
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  marginTop: '10%',
  p: {
    margin: '0 auto',
    color: props.theme.colors.blueAlt,
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontSize: '.75em',
    fontWeight: 600
  }
}))
```

Comment: The flex property would need to be on the `a` tag not on the container.

Comment: That worked for most of it! I'm still seeing that gap between the SVG and the ```<p>``` element but they're both on the same line now! Any idea why the gap is there?